Diffeomorphism of graph with conditions on volume from
I have the following situation: I have a graph $G$ embedded into $\mathbb{R}^2$, with $(0,0)$ a vertex, and I have a diffeomorphism $g$ of the plane. Let's call $G' = g(G)$ the new graph.
I suppose the for each edge $e$ of $G$, $e$ is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$ diffeomorphically.
Moreover, suppose that an edge of $G$ exiting $(0,0)$ is fixed by $g$.
Can I find a new diffeomorphism $g'$ of the plane, such that $g'(G) \subseteq G'$, and $g'_\ast (dx \wedge dy)|_G = dx\wedge dy$?
I tried many different strategies:

change $g$ thorugh Moser's trick, but I cannot impose that $G$ is sent into $G'$
manually "retract" the edges of $g(G)$, in order to change the volume form $g_\ast(dx \wedge dy)$. If I can extend this to "diffeomorphism mod the 1-scheletron", I can meet the conditions in the classical article of Munkres, to extend it to a diffeomorph of the plane.
(Obstructions to the Smoothing of Piecewise-Differentiable Homeomorphism, Ann. Math)
I can extend a continous isotopy of graphs to a family of omeomorphism of the plane. However, the obtained omeomorphism can be really bad, far from the condition of Munkres. This last approach was thought after reading the followin question:
Extensions of non-smooth isotopies of not-submanifolds on surfaces

Can domebody give me a hint? It's also possible that the question has negative answer, or only a local one. The important part is that the edge fixed by $g$ is not touched.

The only possible obstruction that I can see is at the endpoints of the edge that you wish to fix (pointwise, is it?). Have you checked that you can solve the problem at those points? For the rest, I would expect that one can glue local solutions.
